# Linux equivalent of WaitForSingleObject when reading a from console?

Tags: c, linux, winapi

In my Windows application, I use `WaitForSingleObject()` when reading from a console:

```
HANDLE h = (void*)GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
char buf[512] = { 0 };
DWORD r = 0;

if (WaitForSingleObject(h, 3000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    ReadConsole(h, buf, 512, &r, 0);
}
```

It looks like, in order to port the above code to Linux, I have to implement a conditional wait. How would I implement that? How can I check if some characters have been written to the console before reading them?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). I believe that library allows you to wait for keyboard input and to also specify a timeout.

Comment: The good thing is ncurses is cross platform so it works in Windows, macOS, linux, Solaris, bsd ... so you can change your windows code to use ncurses and it can work the same on many other OSs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A close equivalent to the Windows code is as follows:

```c
    int h = STDIN_FILENO;
    char buf[512] = { 0 };
    ssize_t r = 0;
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    int ret;

    fds[0].fd = h;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    ret = poll(fds, 1, 3000);
    if (ret > 0 && (fds[0].revents & POLLIN) != 0)
    {
        r = read(h, buf, 512);
    }
```

This uses declarations from `#include <unistd.h>` and `#include <poll.h>`.

The `poll()` function waits for various specified events on specified file descriptors and has a timeout specified in milliseconds. A timeout value of `-1` allows `poll()` to wait indefinitely (like a timeout value of `INFINITE` in calls to `WaitForSingleObject()` on Windows). On successful completion it returns a positive value indicating the number of `pollfd` structures that have events pending (i.e. have a non-zero `.revents` member). (It is also possible for some special events to be reported in the `.revents` member that were not asked for in the `.events` member.) On timeout it returns 0. On error it returns `-1` and `errno` (defined by `#include <errno.h>`) contains the error number.

Special events in the `.revents` member include `POLLERR` (indicating an error has occurred on the file descriptor), `POLLHUP` (indicating a "hang-up" state on the file descriptor), and `POLLNVAL` (indicating the specified file descriptor is invalid).

The `read()` function call could block indefinitely, but if the file descriptor is something other than a regular file it typically does not block if the file descriptor is ready to be read (which has already been tested for in the results of the `poll()` call). (It is also possible to put the underlying file into non-blocking mode using the `fcntl()` function, in which case `read()` would return `-1` and set `errno` to `EAGAIN` if it is not ready. `poll()` does not care about the non-blocking mode.) On success `read()` returns the number of bytes read which may be less than the requested amount. (For special files if there is some data available but less that the requested count, it typically returns what is available rather than blocking indefinitely to try and read the requested amount.) A return value of `0` should be treated as an "end-of-file" condition. (For some devices such as a terminal the "end-of-file" condition is merely a suggestion and is the result of some special input sequence on the terminal.) On failure `read()` returns `-1` and sets `errno` to the error number.

For interactive input from a terminal, there are other things to consider such as the "termios" settings for the terminal. Amongst other things, these control the conditions when input from the terminal is ready to be read. In the default "canonical" mode, input becomes ready on a line-by-line basis. In "noncanonical" mode, input becomes ready depending on other parameters that control the minimum number of characters and/or the time elapsed since the previous `read()` or the previous received character. The "termios" settings can be queried and changed with the `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()` functions declared by `#include <termios.h>` and only work on terminal devices.  (The `isatty()` function declared by `#include <unistd.h>` can be used to test whether a file descriptor refers to a terminal.)

---

Note: Instead of `poll()` you may also encounter the more ancient `select()` or `pselect()` used for the same purpose of waiting for events on file descriptors. These pass the timeout parameter as a pointer to a `struct timeval` (for `select()`) or a pointer to a `struct timespec` (for `pselect()`). `select()` may update the `struct timeval` to indicate how much time was left when it returned (but `pselect()` *does not* modify its `struct timespec`).